# How to sum triangle pixels with OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, gpgpu

I am new to OpenGL ES. I am currently reading docs about 2.0 version of OpenGL ES. I have a triangular 2D mesh, a 2D RGB texture and i need to compute, for every triangle, the following quantities:

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

where `N` is the number of pixels of a given triangle. This quantities are needed for further CPU processing. The idea would be to use GPU rasterization to sum quantities over triangles. I am not able to see how to do this with OpenGL ES 2.0 (which is the most popular version among android devices). Another question i have is: is it possible to do this type of computation with OpenGL ES 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not able to see how to do this with OpenGL ES 2.0

You can't; the API simply isn't designed to do it.

> Is it possible to do this type of computation with OpenGL ES 3.0?

In the general case, no. If you can use OpenGL ES 3.1 and if you can control the input geometry then a viable algorithm would be:

- Add a vertex attribute which is the primitive ID for each triangle in the mesh (we can use as an array index).
- Allocate an atomics buffer `GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER` with one atomic per primitive, which is pre-zeroed.
- In the fragment shader increment the atomic corresponding the current primitive (loaded from the vertex attribute).

Performance is likely to be pretty horrible though - atomics generally suck for most GPU implementations.